# Is There an Equivalent to the `nexttile` MATLAB Function in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

I am interested in a method similar to MATLAB's nexttile function for dynamically creating subplots. This function adds subplots to an existing figure.

According to the description provided by MathWorks:

> nexttile creates an axes object and places it into the next empty tile of the tiled chart layout that is in the current figure. If there is no layout in the current figure, then nexttile creates a new layout and configures it using the 'flow' tile arrangement. The resulting axes object is the current axes, so the next plotting command can plot into it.

You can find more details in the official [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nexttile.html).

I'm currently enumerating the multiple subplots in a specific order. However, this approach assumes prior knowledge of the exact number of subplots, and any changes to the order would require repetitive modifications to the code. Alternatively, using the nexttile function simplifies the process by automatically arranging the subplots without the need for explicit enumeration.

Comment: See: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/24953 and https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/26097

Comment: Here is one approach (found in the above-linked github issues): https://tacaswell.github.io/dynamic-axes-count.html